# Linear mapping coordinate question - need help

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I am given the set $B=[(2,3),(1,2)]$ and $C=[(2,1),(1,1)]$. $L: \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ is the linear mapping such that $[x]_B = [L(x)]_C$ (like coordinate vector stuff).

I am told to find $L[(3,5)]$ and $L[(x1,x2)]$. Where should I begin? I'm not told to find $[L(x)]_C$ explicitly or anything so I'm very confused. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

By using the given definition,
$$[L(3,5)]_C=[(3,5)]_B\ .$$
Solving the equations
$$\lambda_1(2,3)+\lambda_2(1,2)=(3,5)$$
we get $\lambda_1=1$, $\lambda_2=1$ and so
$$[L(3,5)]_C=(1,1)\ .$$
By the meaning of a coordinate vector,
$$L(3,5)=1(2,1)+1(1,1)=(3,2)\ .$$
Try the other one for yourself.  It is exactly the same in principle, you will just have to be careful since you are dealing with unspecified $x_1,x_2$ instead of specific numbers $3,5$.

Comment: awesome thanks I got it!